# In asp.net-mvc, what is the best way to deal with a crowded Shared View folder?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a large ***ASP.NET-MVC*** project and I have a lot of files in the **shared** *View folder*.

I want to group these files (**Views**) to make it easier to understand.  I saw [this blog pos](http://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/03/06/managing-shared-views-folder-for-large-mvc-projects/)t which seems to have the same issue but I would like to avoid an additional dependencies / **dll** in my solution.

Is there anyway to organize the **Shared** *Views directory* without any external dependencies.  I am using the **aspx** View Engine (***NOT*** Razor)

Comment: Why don't you just make sub directories in your `Shared` folder ?

Comment: in regular aspx webforms view engine how do i support subdirectories in Shared folder?

Comment: are you looking to share Views or just Partial Views? or both?

Comment: @Dave A - just partial views

Comment: Then I would suggest grouping them by Controller View Folder or by Area. Is either approach viable?

Comment: Is creating a "naming standard" a possibility?

Answer (score 4):

In ASP.NET MVC, sharing works in multiple ways.

**1) Use the Controller's View Folder.**

Yes, View Engine will always check you Shared folder for a partial view. But before checking the shared folder, the View Engine will check the "active" folder.

So to explain in better detail, take a scenario where you are using ***HomeController***, rendering a View in the "***Home***" View folder, and you are rendering a Partial View called "NavPartial". Before checking your "***Shared***" folder for the Partial View, the View Engine will check your "***Home***" View folder first.

This means that if you need to re-use Partials within a Controller, you can pack them into that Controller's dedicated View Folder.

I find this approach convenient. I organize my project and Controller structure to take advantage.

**2) Use Areas**

If you use Areas, each Area has a dedicated "***Shared***" folder. This is again convenient if your functionality is local to that Area.

Comment: i thought it was obviousl but i do need to share these across controllers

Comment: @leora, what about use of areas?

Answer (score 3):

As the link you provided refers to MVC 3, I created an example for this version. Assuming the example will contain a subfolder named 'Group1', you can create a custom view engine class and add a custom path to the PartialViewLocationFormats collection:

```
public class MyViewEngine : WebFormViewEngine   
{
    public MyViewEngine()
    {
        PartialViewLocationFormats = PartialViewLocationFormats.Union(new[]
            {
                "~/Views/Shared/Group1/{0}.ascx"
            }).ToArray();
    }
}
```

You can of course add additional paths if you have several subfolders in the 'Views/Shared' folder.

Edit the Global.asax file and add MyViewEngine to the ViewEngines.Engines collection in the Application_Start() method:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MyViewEngine()); 
        //the remaining Application_Start implementation follows below
        .....
    }
```

In the sample application I've added two partial views:

- SharedRoot.ascx is located in the 'Views/Shared' folder
- SharedGroup1.ascx is located in the 'Shared/Group1' folder

A sample Index.ascx file would then look like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home Page
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<h2><%: ViewBag.Message %></h2>
<p>
    To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
</p>
<p>
    <%: Html.Partial("SharedRoot") %>
</p>
<p>
    <%: Html.Partial("SharedGroup1") %>
</p>
```

Here is the picture of the sample solution structure:

[image: MVC - partial views in subfolders]

I've also uploaded a sample VS 2012 MVC 3 application:

http://www.biromt.com/samples/MvcSharedViewsInSubfolders.zip

**UPDATE:** Please note you can't use files with the same name in different subfolders with this solution. You will always get only the first partial view (according to the search order) while others will be ignored. So, if you just have to arrange files in the Shared folder among subfolders, this concept is OK. If you add files afterwards or rename some of them, keep this note in mind. See the discussion beneath for more details (thanks, Max).

Comment: I think this would fail if one wants to call for "Asd.ascx" in Folder2 if there's another named the same "Asd.ascx" in Folder1...

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for pointing this out. I've checked it - it doesn't fail, it just uses the first partial view which is found. It's the similar situation as when you have two partial views with the same name - one in the Shared folder and another in the controller's folder - engine uses the one from the controller's folder as the controller folder is before the Shared folder in the search order.

Comment: Yes exactly, that's what I meant. You could never get a call through for the one located in the Folder2. It will always pick the one in Folder1. Not much use of folders if things in them must be uniquely named over all of the folders....

Comment: That's right. However, leora seems to have a lot of files, all in the Shared folder - if she needs to group them in subfolders she should't run into this kind of trouble. Keeping in mind, of course, not to rename or add a file with the same name in different subfolders.

Comment: Ok. Fine. If that's not a requirement for a folder system then... well... ok, It will work! Please update the post and make this limitation very clear so people do not use this method without knowing about it.

Answer (score 3):

that is for what for asp.net mvc is , all can be customizable.

you can do things like this where your structure looks like

[image: Folder Structure]

this is about displaying templates

to display use

```
@Html.Display("","Home/Managable",null)
```

Display is helper extension method that find the partial view and render..

if you want editor based then you can use Editor Templates and Extenstion method is Editor , EditorFor etc..

Example here is in Razor but same applies to aspx view engine also..

Answer (score 1):

Inside the Views folder, Create any folder structure you find works logically for you.

Then just call each view (or partial) using the full relative path to the file. Even if its more typing calling the views, with a good folder structure it will save time as it will be easier and much clearer to see what kind of (logically) view you are calling.

This can also have some performance benefits as view rendering won't need to go look for your views in several possible locations.

I find it very rare benefit in doing it the "convention based way" if it doesn't fit your needs.

---

I might also mention another good tip; remove all default view engines and make sure only the one you are using is registered. This will increase performance as well. Like this:

```
protected void Application_Start() {
    ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
    // ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new WebFormViewEngine());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Follow this tips:

1. Create each `PartialView` into its related Controller Folder *to avoid
   crowded Shared Folder*.
2. Use your own **Naming Convention** for `Shared` items, so cluster
   each subject by using related characters at the beginning of its
   name. And when you Crawl `Shared` Folder, just simply press related key
   to find its group!
3. If you deal with really separate concepts in your project, use
   `Areas`. That is simple way and easy to configure too. Each `Area`
   allows you to have separate `Shared` Folder on it.

Please Don't try to change the logic of Microsoft Platform. They know this trouble better than us. According to my experience, Changing the logic of MVC application in each manner can cause to appear ambiguous errors or functionality. Perhaps an Update to enhance this part be in way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing regular hierarchy then you have just to tell the new folder hierarchy like if I created a Group for shared views:

> [image: group]

then to access a partial view just write:

```
return PartialView("Group1/_Chart", model);
```

Comment: That can show application architecture to user! I always try to hide my techniques.

Comment: which users and how? views never come in url, Url contain information about controller and action.

Comment: But Paths will be shown by inspecting browser. So place example of output result please.

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi nobody can possibly know where the partial view came from by inspecting the page source......